# Add external file to $_FILES array with javascript/jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, expressionengine

I have the following case:

I have a third party plugin in my expression engine site that handles my user registrations. It also handles profile picture uploads (which is part of the registration process).

I want to add a feature for grabbing the user profile picture from Facebook during registration. As I don't want to tinker with the third party plugin, I'm looking for a way to solve this on the client side by sending the profile pic from Facebook directly into the php `$_FILES` array when the registration form is submitted (so the third party plugin can pick it up from there).

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Same origin policy (amongst other things) makes this impossible. The only way to do this is to take information about the user's Facebook account and get it server side using the FB APIs

Comment: Ok thanks. Go ahead and answer the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: no you cannot. Same origin policy (amongst other things) makes this impossible. The only way to do this is to take information about the user's Facebook account and get it server side using the FB APIs